# Iterated if else in R

Tags: r

I have a set of coordinates that are currently in a format without any breaks but with different amounts of digits before the decimal place. EX: 10545 is 105.45 and 94221 is 94.221. I made an if statement that determines if the first digit is a 1 or not if it is it puts 3 digits in front of the decimal, if not it only puts 2 and have tried to put that inside a for loop but it isn't working.

```
for (n in FinalNTSBData$longitude){
  
  if (str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]],1) == 1){
  lon.pre <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]],start = 1, end = 3))
  lon.post <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 4, end = -1))
  } else {
    lon.pre <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 1, end = 2))
    lon.post <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 3, end = -1))
  }
}

FinalNTSBData$longitude <- as.numeric(paste(lon.pre, lon.post, sep = "."))
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error in FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]] :
> attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex

Before I tried to implement the for loop, the code only looked at the first element in the longitude column and applied that rule to the entire data set. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
All I was missing was an extra 1 in the str_sub function. I was comparing the entire string starting at the first element rather than only the first element. Here's the fix:

```
if (str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]],1,1) == 1){
```

Answer (score 4):

The loop should be based on the sequence and not on the elements as we are using the 'n' as index inside the code i.e.

```
for (n in seq_along(FinalNTSBData$longitude)){
  
  if (str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]],1) == 1){
  lon.pre <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]],start = 1, end = 3))
  lon.post <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 4, end = -1))
  } else {
    lon.pre <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 1, end = 2))
    lon.post <- as.numeric(str_sub(FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]], start = 3, end = -1))
  }
}
```

We could make this faster as the functions are vectorized and thus can be applied on the full data

```
library(dplyr)
FinalNTSBData %>%
    mutate(i1 = str_sub(longitude, 1) == 1,
            lon.pre = as.numeric(case_when(i1 ~ str_sub(longitude, start = 1, end = 3), TRUE ~ str_sub(longitude, start = 1, end = 2)),

            lon.post =  as.numeric(case_when(i1 ~ str_sub(longitude, start = 4, end = -1), TRUE ~ str_sub(longitude, start = 3, end = -1)))
```

Comment: I've implemented this and am still running into the same issue. Do you know if there is an error in the if statements?

Comment: @G-O Based on just by going through the code, i couldn't find any.  If you can show an example, it would be great.  Also, these functions are vectorized.  So, you don't really need the loop though. i.e. `ifelse` or case_when will be faster

Comment: @ akrun The first 3 entries from the raw data are 115552, 851217, 922215. Then after they run through the code they come out as 11.5552, 85.1217, 92.22150. The last 2 are correct but the first should be 115.552.

Comment: In the code, I didn't see where you are adding the `.`

Comment: I forgot to include that in the main post, I used: 
```
  FinalNTSBData$longitude[[n]] <- as.numeric(paste(lon.pre, lon.post, sep = ".")
```

Comment: @G-O why is the last one 92.22150 i.e. the 0 at the end when your condition is based on first character which is 1